# The GNU Linear Programming Kit

Tags: linear-programming, cplex

Has anyone used the GLPK for production systems?
I have an application currently powered by CPLEX and wish to replace it with a free software alternative.

It is used to solve a large MIP (thousands of variables) for a scheduling problem.
I would like to know whether GLPK is mature enough to handle this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been using GLPK on 200,000+ variable problems - solves them in a few seconds, so yes if you can define your problem and don't mind C/C++ it's fine.

Comment: Are you solving a 200,000 variable MIP with GLPK?  Be careful with what you recommend, the difficulty of MIP's varies a lot, even among problems of the same number of variables.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure about GLPK as I do not have much experience
with it. I am able to recommend
https://projects.coin-or.org/Clp

It is open-source, written by IBM Research as part of their
COmputational INfrastructure for Operations Research
(COIN-OR) group.

Let me know how it works!
Good luck,
m

Comment: For a c# wrapper check out http://astarte.csr.unibo.it/coinORwrapper/coinORwrapper.htm